# JPlayer rtmp streaming issue

Tags: jquery, rtmp, jplayer

I am trying to play mp3 stream sample via rtmp with Jplayer (patched https://github.com/rmhall/jPlayer to allow rtmp).
My code is here:

```
$('#jquery_jplayer').jPlayer({
            swfPath: "/Scripts/JPlayer/",
            supplied: "rtmpa, rtmpv, mp3",
            solution: "flash",
            ready: function () {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                    rtmpa: "rtmp://limelight-fmstream-70.musicnet.com/a4396/e1/mp3:/spl/068/771/139/spl_024?e=1342014373&h=0dc0153ed7fb0ff34d04fce764de9896" //this is not work
                    //THIS WORKS! rtmpv: "rtmp://cp67126.edgefcs.net/ondemand/mp4:mediapm/ovp/content/test/video/spacealonehd_sounas_640_300.mp4"
                });
                $(this).jPlayer("play");       
            }
        });
```

if I am playing rtmpv video it works, but this audio(rtmpa) doesn't work(doesn't play anything). I tested this mp3 on http://widgets.mndigital.com/test/stream.aspx and it works there.

Anybody can help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems JPlayer (https://github.com/rmhall/jPlayer ) has issues with RTMP audio playback. I suggest to use JWPlayer instead of it.

Answer (score 1):

if you're interested in a more modern front-end design compared to JWPlayer (w/ RTMP/HTML5 playback), i'd suggest checking out this library I recently released:

it's an audio player framework that leverages SoundManager2 AND integrates w/ jQuery as a $.fn. -- very simple to use and/or customize.. similar to jPlayer in the front-end design, but w/ additional playback capabilities (eg RTMP streaming, full HTML5 support), examples, tests etc:

https://github.com/APMG/APMPlayer

Comment: thanks! will look to your library. I am tried both JWPlayer and JPlayer on another project but both was not ideal. Also will try your lib for rtmp. looks very interesting thanks.

Comment: yep.  sounds like about the same process i went through in vetting out possible off the shelf solutions.  soundManager2 is a great library.. gets updated often and have no complaints about it.  developer (scott) is very responsive to bugs/issues as well.